# What is the proper way to use Prisma ORM types

Tags: typescript, orm, prisma, prisma-orm

I have been having some sort of toruble with prisma typings for a while, So I am trying  to look for suggetions to improve this.

Check the following model and the type generated to Team.

```
//Model
model Team {
    id        BigInt   @id @default(autoincrement())
    createdAt DateTime @default(now())
    updatedAt DateTime @updatedAt

    name              String
    code              String
    founded           Int
    national          Boolean
    logo              String
    country           Country         @relation(fields: [countryId], references: [id])
    countryId         BigInt
    logs              TeamLog[]
    fixturesAsHome    Fixture[]       @relation("home")
    fixturesAsVisitor Fixture[]       @relation("visitor")
    teamApiSource     TeamApiSource[]
}

//Generated type

/**
 * Model Team
 * 
 */
export type Team = {
  id: bigint
  createdAt: Date
  updatedAt: Date
  name: string
  code: string
  founded: number
  national: boolean
  logo: string
  countryId: bigint
}
```

Check the following criterias, and the resulting types in team variable

```
const team =  await db.team.findFirst({
            where: {
                id:  BigInt(10),
            },
        })

// generated type
const team: Team

const team  = await db.team.findFirst({
            where: {
                id:  BigInt(10),
            },
            include: {
                country: true,
                logs: true
            }
        })

// generated type
const team: Team & {
    country: Country;
    logs: TeamLog[];
}
```

So, for any include I have to do, I will get a different type, which sounds cool at first, but it has been quite annoying and generating lots of refactoring

There are some cases, where I need to use a Team as input of a function for example, I have two options if I want the input to have country or logs,

- Set the team type as Team & { country: Country, logs: TeamLog[] }
- Create a new type for my need `TeamWithCountryAndLogs = { Team & { country: Country, logs: TeamLog[] }`

Both looks to noisy to me, How are you guys handling this kind of stuff? In Java JPA, We usually map the whole table and relationships, then I will have only one type Team, with getCountry(), and getLogs(), that would throw exceptions if they are not loaded, not sure if that solution is good also, but is easier typed.

I'm looking for solutions to improve the development life cycle with prisma.
Does prisma generate a "full type" or something like that? WIth all the includes of that type?

One solution that I am thinking about is to generate my own types and use the prisma types only on the database layer. I think I should have done this from the start.But prisma typings were to attractive at first sight.

Any suggestions?